# Find out why I'm getting HTTP 400 error codes when trying to post data

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an order by sending it as a POST request  via my DRF API but I keep getting  "*"POST /shop/orders/ HTTP/1.1" 400 81*" errors.
The error says *"{"total_price":["This field is required."],"puppies":["This field is required."]}"* even though I'm supplying it.
The GET is working fine but I only have orders that I manually wrote in the DB.

Our project is a fictional webshop where you can put dog babies in your cart and order them. The three main models that we have are Users, Orders and Puppies. Because every order has a list of puppies and every puppy has its own amount we needed an intermediary model for the two as a simple ManyToManyField apparently can't handle extra columns. This makes things much more complicated (at least for someone who is new to Django).

I can't find anything on the internet for this special case. I have been trying to get this to work for almost a week now and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Puppy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    description_de = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    description_en = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    puppies = models.ManyToManyField(Puppy, through='PuppyOrder')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class PuppyOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    puppy = models.ForeignKey(Puppy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_address(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Address.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_address(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.address.save()
```

Fetch in react:

```
async function createOrder(order) {
  order = order.map(element =>
    element = {'puppy' : element.puppy.id, 'amount': element.amount}
  )
  let orderReq = {"total_price": "500.00", "puppies": order}
  console.log(JSON.stringify(orderReq))
  const res = await fetch(REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + `/shop/orders/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ orderReq })
    })
  return res.json()
}
```

Console.log results in: *{"total_price":"500.00","puppies":[{"puppy":2,"amount":3},{"puppy":4,"amount":4}]}*

"500.00" is just a placeholder value. Next step will be finding a place to calculate the total_price.

views.py:

```
from shop.models import Puppy, Order
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import permissions, status, viewsets, generics
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework_jwt.serializers import VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer
from .serializers import UserSerializer, UserSerializerWithToken, OrderSerializer, PuppySerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'orders': reverse('order-list', request=request, format=format),
        'puppies': reverse('puppy-list', request=request, format=format),
    })


class OrderList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    print("Test")
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user is None or self.request.user.is_anonymous:
            self.request.user = get_request_user_and_validate_token(self)
        return Order.objects.all().filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print(self.request.data)
        if self.request.user is None or self.request.user.is_anonymous:
            self.reqest.user = get_request_user_and_validate_token(self)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print('Creating new order...')
            serializer.create(user=self.request.user, puppies=self.request.data)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class OrderDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user is None or self.request.user.is_anonymous:
            self.request.user = get_request_user_and_validate_token(self)
        return Order.objects.all().filter(user=self.request.user)


class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all().select_related('address')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all().select_related('address')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class PuppyList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset = Puppy.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PuppySerializer


class PuppyDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset = Puppy.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PuppySerializer


def get_request_user_and_validate_token(self):
    print(self.request.user)
    token = self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', " ").split(' ')[1]
    data = {'token': token}
    try:
        valid_data = VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer().validate(data)
        print(valid_data['user'])
        return valid_data['user']
    except ValidationError as v:
        print("validation error", v)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from .models import Order, Puppy, PuppyOrder


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'orders')


class UserSerializerWithToken(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Code dealing with JWT token creation ... 


class PuppySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    description = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_description(self, puppy):
        return {'DE': puppy.description_de, 'EN': puppy.description_en}

    class Meta:
        model = Puppy
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'image_url', 'age', 'weight', 'description')


class PuppyOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    puppy = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='puppy.id')

    class Meta:
        model = PuppyOrder
        fields = ('puppy', 'amount')


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    puppies = PuppyOrderSerializer(source='puppyorder_set', many=True)
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    total_price = "100.00"

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'total_price', 'puppies', 'date', 'user')
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The response from DRF contains the errors, ie the reason why the post is invalid. If you're not showing it in your react code, you can at least see it in the browser's network tab. But just for a start, your PuppyOrderSerializer has `puppy` as a read only field, but you are sending it in your post.

Comment: Good to know, I edited the question accordingly, thanks! I got the readOnlyField from a tutorial, that looks indeed like the problem... Do you know what else I can use at this spot? Also, the error seems to indicate that the JSON is malformed but it looks okay to me